# Выборка mysql без пустых дат или как обработать PHP

Tags: php, mysql

есть таблица базы данных:

```
id  | services |  data
1   |  ;%      |  0000-00-00
2   |  ;%      |  2015-08-20
```

подскажите или как сделать выборку что бы не участвовало 0000-00-00 или как обработать php так что бы не считать вхождение. Т.е. мне надо посчитать сколько services с заполнеными датами но не с 0000-00-00 которые стоят по умолчанию. Учитывая что уменя итак запрос вот такой.

```
SELECT catalog.id, services.* FROM catalog, services WHERE user=11 AND DATE BETWEEN '2015-08-16' AND '2015-08-23' and services.familyNumber= catalog.id
```

Comment: `select count(*) from table where data<> '0000-00-00'`

Comment: хорошо а если мульти запрос выглядит он так                              SELECT catalog.id, services.* FROM catalog, services WHERE user=11 AND DATE BETWEEN '2015-08-16' AND '2015-08-15' and  and services.familyNumber= catalog.id и таблица serveces

Comment: сделай по дефолту data как NULL, в итоге на backend и в запросе не придется извращаться со строкой

Comment: >>> хорошо а если мульти запрос выглядит он так ... : то во вхождение BETWEEN даты формата 0000-00-00 не будут включены

Comment: как-то  все ругают mysql за between с датами :(

Comment: @ splash58 вы оказались прав если оформите ответ соглашусь.

Comment: @Invision а так разве можно у меня несoздавался объект data?

Comment: @splash58 есть альтернатива between ?

Comment: @Sergalas например, мой вариант. или пишите `a >= startdate and a <= enddate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы в выборку из таблицы не попадали строки, содержащие определенные значения, эти значения надо отфильтровывать в условии WHERE.

Например, если мы хотим, чтобы в выборку попали строки, в которых значение логика равно нулю, то мы пишем

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE logic = 0
```

Данное правило относится к любым типам данных.

Comment: Вы точно уверены в своем условии?